# Creating a Facebook.JsonArray object from a string, for testing purposes

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) in my project and for testing purposes would like to be able to stub out the `FacebookClient` and insert my own fake client which will return pre-defined responses to Facebook API calls (I'm only calling the `FacebookClient.Get` method in my application). Achieving this is pretty easy using a factory pattern and a configurable StructureMap setup.

Apart from one thing...

My fake `FacebookClient` needs to return [`Facebook.JsonArray`](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/blob/master/Source/Facebook/SimpleJson.cs#L80) objects.

I've been sifting through the SDK source code, and can see that the [`SimpleJson`](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/blob/master/Source/Facebook/SimpleJson.cs#L473) class can be used to create `JsonArray` objects. However it is marked as internal, unless I start messing around and rebuilding the SDK.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You could use the `SimpleJson` class through reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself; [`FacebookClient.DeserializeJson`](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/blob/master/Source/Facebook/FacebookClient.cs#L191) does the trick, although it is deprecated.

```
var content = /* Previously obtained JSON string */;

var client = new Facebook.FacebookClient();

var result = client.DeserializeJson(content, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use SimpleJson directly. You can get it via the "SimpleJson" NuGet package or on Github. Basically, we don't want people using the Facebook C# SDK as a JSON serializer - which is why we marked the methods you referenced as deprecated.

Github Source: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json

Comment: Many thanks Nathan. I had not realised that SimpleJson was available separately. I will update my approach accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using `Facebook.Moq` for testing purposes.
https://github.com/prabirshrestha/Facebook.Moq

Install-Package Facebook.Moq

```
var mockFb = FacebookMock.New();

mockFb
    .FbSetup()
    .ReturnsJson("{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"Mark Zuckerberg\",\"first_name\":\"Mark\",\"last_name\":\"Zuckerberg\",\"link\":\"http:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/zuck\",\"username\":\"zuck\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"locale\":\"en_US\"}");

var fb = mockFb.Object;

dynamic result = fb.Get("/4");

Assert.Equal("Mark Zuckerberg", result.name);
```